# How can I add fields to a block?

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm learning Drupal 8 after working with 7 for a number of years and I'm a bit unsure how to approach this. I need to be able to add a block and have it appear on a few specific pages.

I also need to be able to add some text and a link to this block. Is there a way to add these as fields to the block that can be filled in when the block is added to the page?

It looks like I could accomplish something similar by creating a new content type with those fields and adding it as an "Entity view" but this seems like overly complicated.

Is there another way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Custom block type (admin/structure/block/block-content/types/add) and then add fields to it (admin/structure/block/block-content/manage/YOUR_BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME/fields).

You will see that you have the *Manage form display* and *Manage display* tabs too like the content types, you don't need to create a content type. In Drupal 8 you can use blocks in more than one region.

Check [The Block System is Finally Useful in Drupal 8](https://drupalize.me/blog/201403/block-system-finally-useful-drupal-8) and see the video.